# Android. Textview on click disable keyboard

Tags: android, timepicker

I want to call date picker dialog on text view click, but then appears keyboard. Is it possible to do not show keyboard and show `DatePickerDialog` instead?

I added `onclick` method in xml:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/eventDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
        android:hint="Data" />
```

Comment: but why are you using an EditText then?

Comment: You are using an EditText, not a textView. Is that really what You wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/editTextStyle"/>
```

I should use it for dates but I prefer the spinnerStyle.